Adding HTML Button to Draftail Editor Action Buttons in Wagtail
I am having an issue wrapping my head around adding a custom button in Wagtail to the RichTextEditor buttons, where when clicked, a user of the editor is able to add a link with an html button.
The code I used for this in TinyMCE was originally provided here: https://dev.to/codeanddeploy/tinymce-add-custom-button-example-399m
But I can't figure out how to register a hook in Wagtail to implement that type of functionality. There is a similar example here, but I can't figure out how to enable the actual button to be rendered with style we predefine like I had done in TinyMCE editor.
Here is an example that works fine for this use case, but I am hoping there is a simple one with the idea to add buttons like I had done with TinyMCE: https://erev0s.com/blog/wagtail-list-tips-and-tricks/#add-a-code-button-in-the-rich-text-editor
Here is the code from that post:
from wagtail.core import hooks

@hooks.register("register_rich_text_features")
def register_code_styling(features):
    """Add the <code> to the richtext editor and page."""

    # Step 1
    feature_name = "code"
    type_ = "CODE"
    tag = "code"

    # Step 2
    control = {
        "type": type_,
        "label": "</>",
        "description": "Code"
    }

    # Step 3
    features.register_editor_plugin(
        "draftail", feature_name, draftail_features.InlineStyleFeature(control)
    )

    # Step 4
    db_conversion = {
        "from_database_format": {tag: InlineStyleElementHandler(type_)},
        "to_database_format": {"style_map": {type_: {"element": tag}}}
    }

    # Step 5
    features.register_converter_rule("contentstate", feature_name, db_conversion)

    # Step 6. This is optional
    # This will register this feature with all richtext editors by default
    features.default_features.append(feature_name)


I think you would be better of creating a Block to add your call to action button. When I want something like this, I use a StructBlock with the text, url, and style options https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/topics/streamfield.html#structblock

Great thanks, I will take a look. New to wagtail and trying to speed along learning...do you perhaps have an example I can look at in how you've done it in the past, or do you suggest we just mess around and see how it can work for our case?

These are not well maintained and use the old text editor but you can copy some of the blocks and templates into your own project and then edit from there. Example: https://qa.sites.caltech.edu/  Code: https://github.com/caltechads/wagtail-jetstream/blob/master/jetstream/blocks.py#L266
